# Comparing the value of a property in two instances

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I think I'm having boxing issues

```
foreach(var p in item.GetType().GetProperties().
    Where(p => p.GetValue(original, null) is ValueType))
{
    var originalValue = p.GetValue(original, null);
    var modifiedValue = p.GetValue(item, null);
    if (!originalValue.Equals(modifiedValue)) 
        kvpData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", p.Name, originalValue);
}
```

`originalValue` is never equal to `modifiedValue`, Im guessing it's because they are boxed inside Object. But how do I fix it?

Comment: What type are those properties?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that original and item are different instances and have different property values? I tried you method with simple objects like  `var original = new TestObject() { Test = 1 }; var item = new TestObject() { Test = 2 };` and it works.

Comment: Unrelatedly to your question, I would recommend not to retrieve the property twice. Try something like: `foreach (var p in item.GetType().GetProperties()) {  var originalValue = p.GetValue(original, null);  if (!(originalValue is ValueType)) continue;  var modifiedValue = ...` etc.

Comment: You should provide the code for the class that original and item are instantiated from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a boxing issue. `Equals` is a virtual method, which the boxed value types override just fine.

However, I am not sure what the issue is. Could it be that there aren’t actually any matching properties? Remember that `GetProperties()` without any parameters will only return **public** properties. If the properties you need are **private**, you need to add some `BindingFlags`:

```
GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

(I’m assuming here that you don’t want static properties.)

Are you also sure that it is actually **properties** that you are after and not **fields**? Remember that if you declare something as

```
public string Name;
```

then it’s a *field*, whereas

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

is a *property*. If it’s actually fields you need, you need to use `GetFields()` instead of `GetProperties()` with the same binding flags.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is a great tool, but I'm not sure why you're using it here. You're actually causing the set of properties to get iterated twice, which is very expensive. I'd write the code without Linq. Also, there's no need to get the value more than once, which is again very expensive. Give this code a try. It avoids the flaws I pointed out and was comparing correctly when I made and tested a dummy class with it:

```
    foreach(PropertyInfo p in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(ValueType) || p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var originalValue = p.GetValue(original, null);
            var modifiedValue = p.GetValue(item, null);
            if (originalValue != modifiedValue) kvpData.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", p.Name, originalValue);
        }
     }
```

Also, note that strings are not a ValueType although they do implement a value comparison.

Answer (score -1):

From [MSDN: Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) :

> The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for
>   reference types, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference
>   equality means the object references that are compared refer to the
>   same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have
>   the same binary representation.

That means that in your case this 2 objects (if they are reference types) are never point to the same instance.

There is no an easy way to resolve this in so generic way as you would like to do.

But you can implement (*just an example*) an [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) on those types you gonna to compare, and after in this iteration check if the type of the value rturned implements that interface, so cast and call it's implemented [IComparable.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) method.

You can check if the object implements specified interfacce, in this current case IComparable, you can do something like this:

```
originalValue .GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
  x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IComparable))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm guesing that you probably got downvoted because the code presented in the question already attempts to restrict the objects to ValueType, which means it would be using, at worst, ValueType.Equals.

Comment: @JamieSee: if so, it's completely wrong assumption. Cause I clearly suggest implement IComparable for reference types and execute its methods. If the poblem works on value types instead, it clear that the values are never equal (looking on OP's question). So with *this* code there is nothing wrong, but wrong the code that call it.